# html5 getUserMedia Cannot set property 'srcObject' of null

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a basic react component, and I am trying to access video within the navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia. However, I keep getting 'Cannot set property 'srcObject' of null'

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Example extends Component{
    render(){

    const video = document.querySelector('video');
    const constraints = {video:true}
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(

        (stream) => {video.srcObject = stream})

        return(
        <div>
            <video>

            </video>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

the above returns:

Cannot set property 'srcObject' of null

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a React way of streaming video from webcam.

**Using Hooks:**

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserMedia = async () => {
      try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});
        videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    getUserMedia();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <video 
        ref={videoRef}
        autoPlay
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Using Class Component:**

```
class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.videoTag = React.createRef()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // getting access to webcam
   navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({video: true})
    .then(stream => this.videoTag.current.srcObject = stream)
    .catch(console.log);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <video 
        ref={this.videoTag}
        autoPlay
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I get nothing. No error anymore, but just a blank video block. The camera is on, but no video.

Comment: Did you add the `autoPlay` prop?

Comment: i did, but i added autoplay, not autoPlay. its there now, thank you!

Comment: what if am using a functonal component? am using this same way of your's but am getting the same error

Answer (score 3):

Video object is null because in render method you first select this object by querySelector  but video component Not rendered yet, thereupon this dom node not exist and returns null.

You should use componentDidMount lifecycle method for ensure dom object or component is mount and then select dom node.
Meanwhile, I suggest you in react for select dom  nodes use React ref instead of pure javascrip dom selector methods.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Example extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.videoRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const video = this.videoRef.current;
    const constraints = { video: true }
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(
      (stream) => { video.srcObject = stream })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <video autoPlay={true} ref={this.videoRef} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still facing this issue after removing  <React.StrictMode> it works fine

My Context file

```
const myVideo = useRef();
  const userVideo = useRef();
  const connectionRef = useRef();
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
      .then((currentStream) => {
        setStream(currentStream);

        myVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
      });

    socket.on("me", (id) => {
      setMe(id);
    });
    socket.on("callUser", ({ from, callerName, signal }) => {
      setCall({ isReceivedCall: true, from, callerName, signal });
    });
  }, []);
```

My index JS

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <React.StrictMode> 
    <ContextProvider>
      <App />
    </ContextProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

video js

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";

import { SocketContext } from "../context/SocketContext";

const VideoCard = () => {
  const { myVideo } = useContext(SocketContext);

  return (
    <div className="video--card">
      <video playsInline ref={myVideo} autoPlay width="100px" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoCard;
```

let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

When we initialize useRef hook we set the initial value: useRef(0).

So, stream is an object, instead of setting initial value empty or null pass an object.

```
const videoRef = useRef({});
```